# Which is valid format of :only-countries using VuePhoneNumberInput?

Tags: vuejs2

Which is valid format of :only-countries using VuePhoneNumberInput ?
I try :

```
<VuePhoneNumberInput
        v-model="profileRow.phone"
        @update="onUpdate"
        :only-countries="[ 'es', 'en', 'us' ]"
/>
```

and got console error :

```
[Vue warn]: Error in nextTick: "Error: Key is undefined on item (keyField is 'null')"

found in

---> <RecycleScroller>
       <CountrySelector>
         <MazPhoneNumberInput>
```

Looking into source files I tried:

```
<VuePhoneNumberInput
        v-model="profileRow.phone"
        @update="onUpdate"
        :only-countries="[ ['Afghanistan', 'af', '93'], ['Albania', 'al', '355'] ]"
/>
```

but got the same error.

```
"vue": "^2.6.11",
"vue-phone-number-input": "^1.1.9",
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using lower case ISO2 country codes, you need to use all caps code like:

```
:only-countries="[ 'ES', 'US', 'AF', 'AL' ]"
```

Also, please verify for which country `en` is the code, If you meant to use the country code for "Great Britain", then you will need to use `GB` instead.